# Check For CSS Differences Between OS's

Tags: html, css

I have an app that runs across a few different computers and I develop on Ubuntu using Chrome.

Normally my CSS layouts look ok on PC's running Windows, but I've been noticing that a few of my layouts will break when viewing on my co-worker's computers (instead of being side-to-side with floats, will break to a new line for example).

Generally removing a couple pixels on either side will take care of the inconsistencies. This got me to thinking, is there any way to check the display differences on CSS between OS's?  Generally there are guidelines on cross-browser styling, but I don't seem to remember any places that show the differences between OS's.

Comment: Why not just use a CSS reset?

Comment: +1 Reset CSS for a consistent baseline, always.

Comment: +1 for CSS reset but I'd be interested to hear an example of where styling works cross browser but is negatively affected by the OS. Screen resolution, yes yes yes; operating System, no no no.

Comment: @j08691 Guys, relax.  Totally using a CSS reset.

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica Good stuff :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, the problems you're seeing aren't related to the OS so much as which fonts are being used and precisely how they're rendered.  Using default fonts, "ABC" might render 16px wide on Windows but only 15px wide on your flavor of Linux.

In general, it's a good idea to add in a little extra tolerance when sizing a box based on how long (in pixels) the text inside of it is.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, I think the pieces that I've seen broken had a FontAwesome icon lying around.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to test your css in different browsers. You must install as many browsers possible in your machine and check periodically.

Also, there are tools that render your site in different browsers and you can see snapshots.

like this one: http://browsershots.org/

it has a big list of browsers/OS to check.

Comment: This particular website won't work in my case.  This site is only viewable after logging in, and I'm not comfortable creating logins just to check CSS layouts tbh.  Thanks for the suggestion though.